# pgAdmin doesn't show column names after creating a copy of a table

Tags: pgadmin

For instance, if I create a copy of a table using:

```
CREATE TABLE new 
AS
SELECT * FROM old
```

pgAdmin will not show the column names when I right click on the table and then choose `View Data -> View Top 100 Rows`

Comment: What do you mean "without column names". You can't have a table "without column names". The statement you have shown will most definitely preserve the column names from the table `old`.

Comment: What do you see if you do `select * from new`? There will be column names if the table was created.

Comment: Btw, it goes without saying that your table isn't really called new as it's a reserved word...

Comment: Thanks for You answers. If I do 
> select * from new 
I see content with the column names but if I do it in pgAdmin (right click on the table -> View Data -> View Top 100 Rows) I get only content...

Comment: Ben Thurley - I know that 'new' is reserved word. I put only example, my table has a different name.

Comment: Then this isn't a "Postgres" question but a pgAdmin question.

Comment: Ok, thank You for edit my question.

Comment: See here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/7f2a8/1

Comment: So, the question is: why pgAdmin behaves different?

Answer (score 0):

Postgres as feature that suites what you need, called Inheritance. You create a table with the columns you need after all the tables that Inherit from your base table have the same structure.

Example:
You've a base table called invoices (don't insert data here....), you create a table that Inherits called invoices_2016 and othe invoices_2017(you can insert directely or create triggers to insert in the correct table), when you select from Invoices_2016 you only see the records from that table... if you select from Invoices postgres will return records from Invoices_2016 anda Invoices_2017 (all tables that Inherit from Invoices).

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-inherit.html

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. For those who don't understand the problem OP described (i.e. everyone), what happens is that the column names are perfectly visible when running a sql query, but the top grey line in pgadmin (where the names and types should be) are blank. In addition, "Rows (estimated)" are 0 and every table view gets a warning about how you should run VACUUM.

Turns out pgadmin gets confused if you have a window open and then do some major operation, e.g. drop, create and populate a table. If I close pgadmin and reopen after the SQL updates have finished it behaves normally. Seems like a bug to me.